# How do I convince JsonResponse to serialize a custom class?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, serialization

I'm using Django 3.0.6 with Python 3.7.

My views/controllers return a `JsonResponse`, like that:

```
    return JsonResponse({
        'My IP string': champion.ip_string,
        'Chiefdom full name': chiefdom.FullName(),
        'Chiefdom': chiefdom, # This will raise an exception
    })
```

I would like to **upgrade the Chiefdom class** to behave nicely with `JsonResponse`.

The most obvious way to do that to me would be to **override a method** that `JsonResponse` is going to call to serialise this (I guess? It has to, come on…), but… I haven't been able to find any information at all regarding that.

**The whole point of this question is NOT modifying the VIEW**. Only modify the Chiefdom class itself, in a way that then `JsonResponse` suddenly decides that "oh well now it is indeed serialisable".

*I could only find information that involves modifying the view itself, or stuff even more convoluted. There's tons and tons of irrelevant information, and if what I'm searching for is there somewhere, it was buried under piles of other stuff.*

Comment: @ o0'. what do you have inside ```chiefdom``` ?

Comment: Ideally it should not matter, because the whole point would be to override it and have it return (manually) only what I want to be included in the serialisation. _But if it matters for some reason I can't imagine right now, I'll edit._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to [Arakkal Abu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12578202/arakkal-abu) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049000/207655).*

The solution, that doesn't involve altering the views at all (save for changing the imports), is this one:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse as JsonResponseSuper

class JsonEncoder (DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default (self, obj):
        if callable(getattr(obj, "toJSON", None)):
            return obj.toJSON()

        return super(obj)

def JsonResponse (obj):
    return JsonResponseSuper(obj,encoder=JsonEncoder)
```

And then create a `toJSON` method in the `Chiefdom` class:

```
    def toJSON (self):
        return {
            'IP': self.ip_string,
            'Name': self.dbObject.name,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

pass ***custom encoder*** by specifying the [**`encoder`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse) parameter.

By default, **`JsonResponse`** uses [**`django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder) class.

#### Example:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder


class MyCustomEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    ...


def sample_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({
        'My IP string': champion.ip_string,
        'Chiefdom full name': chiefdom.FullName(),
        'Chiefdom': chiefdom,  # This will raise an exception
    }, encoder=MyCustomEncoder)
```

Comment: Is there instead a way to modify my class so that the default encoder will naturally find a way to serialise it?

Comment: +1 while this doesn't strictly answer the question as asked, it has still moved me in the right direction (I'll post my answer separately)

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think there is an *auto-discover* method to find out the member of your custom class (it can be model, form or any other no-standers oop class)